# xml containing another xml

Tags: xml

We have xml storage format such as

```
<record> data </record>
```

We have hit a use case where data itself can be xml. How can xml data be included inside another xml element such as

```
<record>
```

Comment: Edit your question to include a sample of what it could be.

Comment: if it's a well formed xml then it will fit right in. if it starts with the `<?xml` declaration and/or has a `<!DOCTYPE` to it then you might need to parse it out. is there something else that I am missing? what kind of issue do you experience today trying to embed that another XML into your `<record>` XML?

Comment: @PavelVeller It sounds like if the data does not contain <record> or </record>, everything should work fine.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is perfectly valid for an XML element to contain XML like the following:

```
<record><record>test</record></record>
```

If this is not what you need, please clarify further in your question. As a last resort you may consider using CData Elements.

```
<record>
    <![CDATA[<someotherbadlyformedxml>data<br></someotherbadlyformedxml>]]>
</record>
```

But there really should be no reason to do so if all of your data is valid XML.

Comment: Chris, What if data contains <record> element. Then the output would look like <record><record>abc</record></record>. I guess if namespaces are different, then things should work.

Comment: I am not sure what the problem is here - The XML is still valid (even without different namespaces). Are you having problems selecting the data? What is the challenge you are facing?

Comment: Yes problem with selecting the right <record> element. But like i said, namespaces should solve that problem. To be clear, i dont have any control over what gets stored inside <record> element. So i can only think about some valid xml, but that would cause problem with xpath queries.

Answer (score 2):

You probably don't want to be nesting XML like that if you can help it. But, if you have to, then use CDATA.

Here's a reference to [CDATA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784183/what-does-cdata-in-xml-mean)

Answer (score 2):

Two possible solutions:

1. escape the strings/xml data before you write your record elements.
2. use CDATA sections